# If an item from one list is added to another List - are they referencing the same object?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#, I am wondering about the following scenario. I have the following list declared in **myCurrentClass**

```
private List<someOtherClass> mySteps = new List<someOtherClass>();
```

Suppose there is also another List in my class that can hold object of type **someOtherClass** as well. I don't know how to fully explain this other than saying the library I'm working with provides a property that is a list of objects and it can accept derived types into that list such as my **someOtherClass**. Let's call this other list that is provided by the library **secondList**

Now in the constructor of **myCurrentClass** I do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEPS; i++)
{
        mySteps.Add(new someOtherClass());
        secondList.Add(mySteps[i])
}
```

My question is, is mySteps[i] and secondList[i] referring to the same object? So if somewhere later in the execution of **myCurrentClass** I do something like this:

mySteps[i].someValue = 13;

then SecondList[i].some value will also equal 13?

Comment: Yes.  What happens when you test it and observe the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to make this but **yes**, they are the same object (instance) of `someOtherClass`. That is because when you call `secondList.Add(mySteps[i])`, you will refer to the same (already existing) object `mySteps` in `secondList`.
So: `mySteps[i].someValue = 13`; `secondList[i].someValue` is also `13`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if it's a reference object (`class`) or a value object (`struct`). The former would add the same instance, while the latter would be different instances.